# Applescript wait till a modal disappear

Tags: applescript

I am writing a script to generate PDF for a lot of mails. Because the PDF generation takes some time, I want the script to wait till

[image]

to disappear in Mail. So I can start to process the next one. The following are the attributes of this element.

[image]

Since it has no title, how can I specify to wait  till this element to disappear?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need two repeat loops, one waits until the sheet appears and the other waits uniil the sheet disappears.

```
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "Mail"
        repeat until exists sheet 1 of window 1
            delay 0.5
        end repeat
        repeat while exists sheet 1 of window 1
            delay 0.5
        end repeat
        -- sheet was dismissed
    end tell
end tell
```

Comment: It may not be a bad idea to give the first repeat loop a chance to `exit repeat` in the event that Mail.app unexpectedly quits or is purposely closed while still in that first repeat loop.  Adding this line `if not (exists) then exit repeat -- If Mail Unexpectedly Quits or Closes During Loop` into your `repeat until exists sheet 1 of window 1` event, should take care of that problem if it arises.